# Where is the Autofac InstancePerApiRequest scope disposed?

Tags: c#, autofac, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I am going through the code of both `Autofac.Integration.WebApi` and `Autofac.Integration.WebApi.Owin` and I can see how the `InstancePerApiRequest`/`InstancePerHttpRequest` lifetime scope is being created and kept in the `HttpRequestMessage`, but I cannot see where it is being disposed at the end of the request.

I would expect an `HttpModule` or OWIN middleware to dispose the scope but cannot find it.

Does anyone know where exactly the Autofac `InstancePerApiRequest`/`InstancePerHttpRequest` lifetime scope (tagged `AutofacWebRequest`) is being destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the OWIN middleware integration, the lifetime scope is diposed [here](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/78e3ff71286fab6185ea8a89ae622825afa741a5/Core/Source/Autofac.Integration.Owin/AutofacAppBuilderExtensions.cs#L62) (through the `using` block).

If you're using the regular `AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver`, it's being disposed [here](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/78e3ff71286fab6185ea8a89ae622825afa741a5/Core/Source/Autofac.Integration.WebApi/AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver.cs#L127) (through Web API's [`IDependencyResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.dependencies.idependencyresolver%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) service).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer! But shouldn't I be using both the middleware integration and also setting the AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver? Like this `code` var dependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
            configuration.DependencyResolver = dependencyResolver;

            app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
            app.UseAutofacWebApi(configuration);`code`

Comment: I don't think that's part of the original question, but no, you don't have to use the OWIN part if you don't have any middleware dependent on Autofac.